# How to load Map view using the WebView Url in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, uiwebview

I'm loading a mapview using `UIWebView` by an url like http://www.google.com/maps?saddr=Massachusetts,+United+States&daddr=Sunnyvale,+CA,+United+States. This leads to load a direction view instead of mapview with Direction.

Can any one tell me how to load mapview with directionLine from source to destination using the above url?

Comment: Hi, did you get a solution to this  problem .. I am also looking for a solution of this problem, If you got a solution will be kind enough to post the answer here...

Answer (score 2):

Just add `&output=embed` at the end of your link:

```
http://www.google.com/maps?saddr=Massachusetts,+United+States&daddr=Sunnyvale,+CA,+United+States&output=embed
```